Azure DevOps Pipeline Unable to work with ARM template deployment yaml template for Azure Data Factory Build Pipeline
I am attempting to execute an Pipeline which uses the ARM template deployment to execute pipelines to Azure

The yaml script is as follows:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'NewAzureConnection'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx03'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroupUAT)'
    location: '$(Location)'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf-xxxxabric-dev/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf-xxxxxx-dev/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: '-factoryName $(DataFactoryUAT)'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

The full script is as follows:
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- adf_publish

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- script: |
    tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  displayName: Show file structure of System.DefaultWorkingDirectory during a build


- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'NewAzureConnection'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf-xxxxx-xxxxx-dev/PrePostDeploymentScript.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf-xxxx-xxxx-dev/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroupUAT) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactoryUAT) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      inputs:
        deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
        azureResourceManagerConnection: 'NewAzureConnection'
        subscriptionId: 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx03'
        action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
        resourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroupUAT)'
        location: '$(Location)'
        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
        csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf-xxxxabric-dev/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
        csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf-xxxxxx-dev/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
        overrideParameters: '-factoryName $(DataFactoryUAT)'
        deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

I when I run the pipeline it fails on the task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 with the following error:
##[error]Failed to check the resource group status. Error: {"statusCode":403}

Any thoughts on what is causing the error?
The ARM Template Settings are as follows:

I added 'Data Factory Contributer' to the Subscription and the original problem was resolved, but I now have the following issue



error: ##[error]Failed to check the resource group status. Error: {"statusCode":403}

The error means the service principal used in your Azure DevOps service connection does not have enough permission to perform the action.
To solve the issue, you need to add an Azure RBAC role for the service principal.
You can navigate to the Project Settings  -> Service connections -> find the service connection you used -> select Manage service connection roles.

Then it will open a page for the Azure subscription in Azure portal, navigate to the Access control (IAM) -> add the service principal as a Contributor role. This is the Azure Subscription level Contributor.
Or you can navigate to the target Resource Group -> Access control (IAM) and grant the Contributor role to Service Principal. This is the Resource Group level Contributor.
Then you can re-run the Pipeline to deploy the ARM template in Azure Pipeline.
Note: To assign the role for your service principal, your user account  needs to have the RBAC role e.g. Owner, User Access Administrator.

I added Data Factory contributor to the Managed service connection role, but I now have a new issue, please see updated question

@Patterson From the error message, it seems that the issue is related to the content of the ARM template. May I know if you can directly deploy the ARM template without Azure DevOps Pipeline?

You can refer to the steps in this doc to directly deploy the ARM template in Azure Portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal#retrieve-a-custom-template

I will try and deploy the ARM template in Azure Portal. However, its very strange that I'm getting this error.

I think I will support a new question, as my original question was resolved by your first answer

@Patterson If you encounter the same issue when deploying the ARM template from Azure Portal, the issue should be related to ARM template itself. In this case, it can be a good choice to create a new ticket and share the related ARM template file content for further troubleshooting about the issue

Yes. You are correct.
